# Visual Studio web test Recorder : Error- The centricity's container for .Net-based pages faild to initialize

Tags: .net, performance, visual-studio-2012, fiddler, web-testing

I'm trying to record performance test script using Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate.

while recording test script using Web Test Recorder I'm getting this error (Please find Error Screenshot below.)[image]

Note : There are certain plugins installed on client side to access this application using IE browser.

Is there any way to record script using web test recorder with required plugins / add-ons or Is there any other way to record script?

I tried to record .wettest script using fiddler, But unfortunately I'm not able to open this file in Visual Studio.

Comment: Did you do Fiddler menu => **File** => **Export sessions** => **All sessions** => select export format as **Visual Studio Web Test** and create a `.webtest` file?

Comment: @AdrianHHH yes, I'm following same steps.

Comment: What happens when you try and open Fiddler's `.webtest` file in Visual Studio?

Comment: It gives popup message - The Web test could not be loaded: The specied Web test cannot be opened.

Comment: That message often means that the file is open or locked by some other program. I do not recall every getting that message after using Solution explorer's **Add** => **Existing item** and then double-clicking the `.webtest` in Solution explorer. Occasionally Visual Studio gets confused but I have always found that all is OK after closing all copies of Visual Studio and then reopening the solution.

Comment: @AdrianHHH I've noticed one point recently,If i remove all request with content type **application/octet-stream** and generate **.webtest** file.Then it would open in Visual Studio.

Comment: A `.webtest` file is just XML. Can you open it with a text editor and copy a small request containing `application/octet-stream` (from `<Request...` to `</Request>` inclusive to here?

Comment: I tried to look in to .webtest file, but i did not find any request with content type application/octet-stream.